# Firefox frozen, constantly using ~50% CPU, and at 1.6GB RAM usage

Tags: firefox, freeze

Earlier today I went to save a file in Firefox, using the keyboard to switch to the desired folder, when the explorer save box almost became totally unresponsive (The help button, near the close button would change the cursor, but clicking any other control in the dialog didn't produce the usual behaviour).

I then realised that my Firefox windows, with probably ~100 tabs (Only 10-20 loaded), had stopped responding also. The process has been consuming the above resources and no script timeout warning has been displayed in the last several hours of me researching ways to deal with this.

This isn't the first time something similar to this has happened, as I usually leave tabs up until the info in them is no longer useful, which leads to many being loaded at any one time, and more still that are in the tabs list, but left unloaded.

I presume that the symptoms indicate a process is stuck in a endless loop, or is stuck not being able to swap out memory to complete an operation, no?

What I am mainly wondering is - **Is there a way of closing a tab, or something, while Firefox is in this state, to resume some resemblance of normal operation. Perhaps some sort of memory manipulation technique / tool, so in future instances I don't have to start a large non-resumable downloaded again, or this time save some information in a form Lazarus isn't likely to have saved?**

Also, I once read about a limitation of the XUL platform, that was related to maximum RAM size of a instance (or similar), but cannot find any info through google about this now. Would be great if someone could point me to this information again.

Comment: 100 tabs? really? and you're wondering why it's crashing, isn't this question better suited on the Mozilla forums?

Comment: @Sickest (Please read the question again...) 100 tabs *weren't* loaded, hence (normally) not high memory usage, but for those who have spent many years using Firefox (Something I think I should have mentioned now, alongside that this amount of tabs is not uncommon for me) probably agree that it isn't that simple (Depends on other factors, like how long Firefox has been running prior). As to your question - I have much more faith in the users of SE, than what I have seen on the Mozilla forums, and I am not confident I would get this kind of support from Mozilla directly via support channels.

Comment: As an aside, I would wonder how many people use Firefox, as opposed to the competition, for it's better-than-average coping with a large quantity of tabs open. Also, as I am re-looking at the question, would like to add that I have identified Facebook as one site that seems, when left up in Firefox, causing "runaway" memory consumption.